# Extracting live data from website using PHP

Tags: php, regex, extract

I have viewed the question on [Extract data from website via PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2019892/extract-data-from-website-via-php/2020062#2020062) regarding this issue. But I couldn't solve my problem. I am trying to extract a live data from a website. It's silver price. It changes everyday and I need to extract the latest data.

I am trying to extract from http://www.maybank2u.com.my/mbbfrx/silver_rate.htm

I have done file_get_contents("http://www.maybank2u.com.my/mbbfrx/silver_rate.htm");

But when I tried to preg_match() the price. I couldn't find the correct way of doing it. 
Appreciate if someone here could help me.

Sorry for bringing up the same question which are already in the threads, but I just couldn't solve it.

Comment: What regex are you using?

Comment: Regex is not the right tool to parse html.

Comment: I have tried preg_match('/<tr><td>SELLING(RM/\g)</\td></\tr>/'); But I'm not entirely sure about that as well because the price should be changing everyday so I'm guessing it should be something to do with <input> tags.

Comment: show us what u already done..for this sort of problem, using html parser is more appropriate..and hi my countrymen

Comment: As others suggested you using HTML/DOM parsers (and that's right), let me also suggest http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ to test out your regexes.

Comment: Thanks everyone. Solved it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please dont use regex to parse an html document.
Use html/dom parser instead.
Take a look at this link.
It should give you a start how to extract the data.

[Html Parsing](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/html-parsing-and-screen-scraping-with-the-simple-html-dom-library/)

Answer (score 0):

Don't use regular expressions (preg_match). Use a dom parser. I'd recomomend the one at http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/.

Once you have a script that would [scrape](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_scraping) the page you're interested in, instruct your server to execute it every day by setting up a cron job.